# How to draw image object to canvas when the object is from a jQuery selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

In jquery, I do a select statement to get a bunch of img tags. But how do I actually get the object of each one of those that I can use with the drawImage function for canvases? Normally what works is the document get element by id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the object by writing  `$(this)`

For example:

```
   $("img").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).prop("src"));
});
```

in side the loop on  *bunch of img tags* .